# Google Adsense Impressions Not Matching With Analytics

Tags: google-adsense, analytics

I'm using woopra and google analytics on one site. Both are reporting 100 unique visits to one site. Browsers - 70% Firefox, 10% chrome, 15% IE and remaining are others. My adsense stats are showing only 20-30 visits for this website. Even though analytics and other stat programs are showing more visits, adsense counting only 20 or so impressions out of it.

What seems to be the problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a much higher proportion of Firefox users than average, and Firefox users are especially known for using AdBlock. I suspect that you may be recording Analytics hits but not Adsense impressions for this reason, although I'm not really sure if that could explain the entirety of the vast difference you have.

Comment: I just noticed that due to panda update site has lost traffic and now i don't have much data to track. So both adsense and analytics are pretty much low for any comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Adsense reporting is delayed.  Check stats from a specific day a week ago.  See how those figures line up.

Comment: I did that and results are same, impressions seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

As @joshuahedlund already mentioned there are a lot of users that use AdBlock or similar extensions, I just want to add that this is not popular just among Firefox users because there are extensions for Chrome, Opera and Safari with multimillion user base.

Other possibility is that AdSense doesn't show ad for each request, especially if you don't have quality content on each page where you serve ads.

> if Google does not have ads for an AdSense for search query, or if the
>   query will return non-family-safe ads, we will not show any ads

[Do you guarantee to have relevant ads for my site?](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10196)